# LINQ With MongoDB: Join With Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

Mongodb collection join using c# driver and LINQ. I found two relevant solutions list below

```
            var table1 = _myRepo.GetAll();
            var table2 = table1.Where(x => x.Type == "MyType");

            var try1 = (from x in table1
                        join y in table2 on new { a = x.ClaimId, b = x.CensusId } equals
                        new { a = y.ClaimId, b = y.CensusId }
                        select x).ToList();
```

This query will throw exception **The Join query operator is not supported.**

```
            var try2 = (from x in table1
                        from y in table2
                        where x.ClaimId == y.ClaimId &&
                        x.CensusId == y.CensusId select x
                        ).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

This query will throw exception **The SelectMany query operator is not supported**

But below query works

```
            var table1 = _arRepository.GetAll();
            var table2 = table1.Where(x => x.Type == "MyType");

            var claimIds = table2.Select(x => x.ClaimId).Distinct().ToList();
            var censusIds = table2.Select(x => x.CensusId).Distinct().ToList();
            var data = table1.Where(x => claimIds.Contains(x.ClaimId) && censusIds.Contains(x.CensusId));
```

The problem with this is that it loads the (claimIds and censusIds ) in memory, Actually I want to executes this on server so that it return only required data.
I also found a blog for newly mongodb feature (Lookup) discussed in

Blog: https://www.axonize.com/blog/iot-technology/joining-collections-in-mongodb-using-the-c-driver-and-linq/
I flow the blog to install required drivers

```
<PackageReference Include="mongocsharpdriver" Version="2.9.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.9.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.9.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.9.2" />
```

but no success

Comment: I don't think Linq and MongoDB can do joins, but I think you can use the MongoDB .NET driver to do aggregation queries.  https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/05/18/introduction-to-mongodb-with-net-part-29-aggregation-in-the-net-driver-using-strong-typing-and-dedicated-functions/. Aggregation queries allow joins

Comment: yes, i am using MongoDB.NET

Comment: @Cagaya Coper Could you please post the solution for this. I only want to get back the required data from IQueryable join query. See the first two attempts not working for me.

Comment: @barrypicker I found this site https://medium.com/@axonizeltd/joining-collections-in-mongodb-using-the-c-driver-and-linq-5864dc012447 by Janiv Ratson
Here it is mentioned that how to implement, I exactly flow the same but not luck
Please assist